# Cocoapods Installation Error on macOS Sierra 10.12.1

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods, macos-sierra

I'm getting this error when i'm trying to install `cocoapods`:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/fuzzy_match
```

I have **gem** version **2.6.7** installed, **macOS 10.12.1**
can anyone help please..or have instructions how to install **cocoapods** on **10.12.1**

Comment: Installing CocoaPods App https://cocoapods.org/app also solve the issue..

Answer (score 15):

I have a similar problem and it solved by using 2nd solution,
try to run these commands **either in solutions 1 or 2** at terminal

I'm running osx 10.12.1

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
>       Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod

**Solution 1:**

step 1 : `sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0"`

step 2 : `sudo reboot`

step 3 : `sudo gem install cocoapods -V`

**Solution 2:**

step 1 : `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

step 2 : `pod setup`

Answer (score 5):

check pod version using command given below

```
pod --version
```

if there is any version installed remove it by using the command

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

restart your mac and reinstall again using the command

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

On MAC OS Sierra10.12.2,
the following steps solve my problem:-

steps:

1. sudo reboot
2. sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
3. pod setup
4. cd specific path
5. pod update

Answer (score 0):

This is how I Cocoapods Installation Error on macOS
Solved.

1. cd ~/.cocoapods
2. rm -r repos
3. sudo gem install cocoapods
4. pod install