# Can't Install Cocoapods on macOS Sierra

Tags: cocoapods, macos-sierra

I'm not able to install CocoaPods on my Mac for my project.

I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.3 and Xcode 8.2.1 (Swift 3)

When running sudo gem install cocoapods I got this error :

> Fetching: cocoapods-core-1.2.0.gem (100%)
>
> Successfully installed cocoapods-core-1.2.0
>
> Fetching: cocoapods-1.2.0.gem (100%)
>
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
>
> Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod

I've try both answers on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263180/cannot-install-cocoapods-on-macos-sierra-10-12-1) but I didn't got any Podfile sadly.

Can anyone please help me ? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this `sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Hey @danh thanks for your help it's written "1 gem installed" but I don't have any Podfile :(

Comment: Change directory to your project folder and type `pod init` to create a Podfile